# Woocommerce ask for the email already given

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My customers can not complete downloadable orders by WooCommerce. System is requesting email address despite it is already fulfill. How can I fix it?

[rejection message: Please, fill email address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE3N3.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that particular product features maybe it is only "downloadable". It also should be "virtual". Just one tick and go.

Source: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-order-status-control/